# Java Jlabel setText

Tags: jlabel

I am a java beginner, i used eclipse to make a gridbaglayout:

```
            import java.awt.EventQueue;
            import javax.swing.JFrame;
            import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
            import javax.swing.JLabel;
            import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;

            public class test4 {
                public static JFrame frame;
                /**
                 * Launch the application.
                 */
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                test4 window = new test4();
                                window.frame.setVisible(true);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    }
                /**
                 * Create the application.
                 */
                public test4() {
                    initialize();
                }
                /**
                 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
                 * @return 
                 */
                public static  void initialize() {
                    frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 137, 89);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
                    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
                    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
                    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
                    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
                    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

                     JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Label");
                    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
                    gbc_lblNewLabel.gridx = 0;
                    gbc_lblNewLabel.gridy = 0;
                    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel, gbc_lblNewLabel);


                }

            }
```

i want to use {lblNewLabel.setText("test");} in {public static void main(String[] args) } or in {private static set(){lblNewLabel.setText("test");}} but it did not work. What should i do? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyNiceApplication {

private Label niceLabel;

   void initialize(){...} //Frame init...

   public void setNiceLabelText(String text){
      niceLabel.setText(text);
   }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
   MyNiceApplication app = new MyNiceApplication();
   app.setNiceLabelText("New LabelText");

}
```

Comment: it's still not working:  MyNiceApplication app = new MyNiceApplication(); // <<<not work here!!!,No enclosing instance of type test4 is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type test4 (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of test4).